# how to fix groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Setup.call() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

**Error**: hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Setup.call() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[CreationDate:2024-01-13]]
Possible solutions: call(groovy.lang.Closure), wait(), any(), wait(long), main([Ljava.lang.String;), each(groovy.lang.Closure)

There are two scripts, the pipeline script where stageone is calling the setup script (in another repo) and is sending the jenkins param createDate.

What can I do to successfully consume this param?  The current def call code is unrelated to this feature so I need to amend what is already there.  I've tried various options but cannot get past the error above.

Pipeline Script:

```
node {
    stage ('stageone') {
        Setup(CreationDate: params.createDate)
    }
```

Setup Script:

```
def call(Closure body) {
    def config = [:]
    if (body) {
        body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
        body.delegate = config
```

Comment: in `Setup.groovy` declare call as: `def call(Map map) {  println map.CreationDate }`

Comment: What about the def call (Closure body) that's already present?

Comment: you are calling it with map `Setup(CreationDate: params.createDate)` but method currently declared with closure parameter... or maybe i don't understand what you are asking...

Comment: Because the (closure body) is already present, I didn't want to disrupt that functionality.  Can they co-exist? def call(Closure body, Map map) @daggett

Answer (score 0):

you could create another call method inside Setup.groovy

```
class StartupScript{            // <=== this just to emulate script in jenkins

    // existing call method calling a new one
    def call(Closure body){ call(null, body) }
    // new call method has 2 params but last one is optional
    def call(Map _config, Closure body=null){
        def config = _config ?: [:]
        if(body){
            body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
            body.delegate = config
            body()
        }
        println "config = ${config}"
        return config
    }

}                               // <=== this just to emulate script in jenkins

def Startup=new StartupScript() // <=== this just to emulate script in jenkins

assert Startup(AAA:"aaa") == [AAA:"aaa"]
assert Startup{AAA="aaa"} == [AAA:"aaa"]
assert Startup(AAA:"aaa"){ BBB="bbb" } == [AAA:"aaa",BBB:"bbb"]
```

or keep one method and check type of argument

```
    def call(Object body){
        if (body instanceof Closure) {
            ...old code here...
        } else if (body instanceof Map) {
            ...new code here...
            println(body.CreationDate)
        } else throw new Exception($"unsupported argument type: ${body?.getClass()}")
    }
```